# Applying Gauss's formula to find flux

Tags: integration, divergence-theorem

Using divergence theorem, find flux of vector field
${\bf F}=\left(x\left(z - 1\right),y\left(z - 1\right),xy\right)$ on the area determined with inequalities
$$
\left(z-1\right)^2\le 4-x^2-y^2,\quad
\left(z-1\right)^2\ge x^2+y^2,\quad z\ge1
$$

- This comes down to calculating the integral $2\displaystyle\iiint_{V}\left(z-1\right)\,\mathrm{d}V$. Then, what is left is to find bounds.
- When I set $z=0$, in the $OXY$ plane I get
  $x^2+y^2\le 1$ and $x^2+y^2\le3$, so it is enough to watch circle with radius $\sqrt3$ and center at origin.
- After cylindrical coordinates I have
  $$
  \left\{\begin{array}{rcccl}
  {\displaystyle 0} & {\displaystyle \le} & {\displaystyle \phi} & {\displaystyle \le} & {\displaystyle 2\pi}
  \\[0.5mm]
  {\displaystyle 0} & {\displaystyle \le} & {\displaystyle r} & {\displaystyle \le} & {\displaystyle \sqrt{3}}
  \\[0.5mm]
  {\displaystyle r + 1} & {\displaystyle \le} &  {\displaystyle z} & {\displaystyle \le}  & {\displaystyle 1 + \sqrt{4 - r^{2}}}
  \end{array}\right.
  $$
  And then I would integrate in order ${\rm d}z, {\rm d}r, {\rm d}\phi$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is all correct except the upper bound of $r$ which should be $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems correct except bound of $r$.

This is a closed surface enclosed by an inverted cone along $z-$axis with vertex at $(0,0,1)$ and a sphere of radius $2$ with center at $(0,0,1)$. Radius of resulting surface is maximum where they intersect which we can find by equating them,

Sphere: $(z-1)^2\le 4-r^2$, Cone: $(z-1)^2\ge r^2$.

At intersection, $4-r^2 = r^2 \implies r = \sqrt2$

So bounds of $r$ is $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt2$.

Comment: Yes... Not sure why I didn't look for intersection :). All clear now. Thanks again!

Comment: Your bounds are correct for $z$ but to make it easier, you can do change of variable,  replace $z-1$ with another variable, say $u$ in the integral. Limits of $u$ will be $r \leq u \leq \sqrt{4-r^2}$